# WPF Label Foreground Color

Tags: wpf, colors, foreground

I have 2 `Label`s in a `StackPanel` and set a `Foreground` color to both of them... 
The second one shows as black, when it shouldn't.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,20,0">
    <Label Content="{lex:LocText CGI, Suffix=:}" Foreground="#FFE0E0E0" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Cgi}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}%" Foreground="#FFE0E0E0" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I checked your XAML, it works fine - e.g. both labels have a gray foreground.
My guess is that you have some style which is affecting the way it looks...

Try moving your XAML to a brand-new window and see for yourself... Then, check if you have any themes or styles (in the `Window.Resources` for instance) which might be affecting the labels...

Comment: Your guess was right. I noticed this behavior since we added the Metro Styles. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Just because I searched how to change the color of a label and it brought me here, I'd like to add that if you simply want to change the color of a label in your code file, this should do: `lblStatus.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`

Comment: or with a bit less code, `lblStatus.Foreground = Brushes.Red;`

Answer (score 7):

The title "WPF Label Foreground Color" is very simple (exactly what I was looking for) but the OP's code is so cluttered it's easy to miss how simple it can be to set text foreground color on two different labels:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Foreground="Red">Red text</Label>
    <Label Foreground="Blue">Blue text</Label>
</StackPanel>
```

In summary, No, there was nothing wrong with your snippet.